# Group Algebra of Direct Product is Tensor Product of Group Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, group-rings

Given groups $G$ and $H$, I want to show that $R[G \times H] \cong R[G] \otimes R[H]$.  I'm not sure why, but I'm struggling with it.  I'd like to map the basis elements from one to the other in the obvious way, that is $$ F:R[G] \otimes R[H] \rightarrow R[G \times H]$$ $$ g \otimes h \mapsto (g,h) $$ but I'm having trouble with the details.  Clearly this is invertible, so I just need to show it respects the algebra structure.  I've got that $$ F((g\otimes h) \cdot (g'\otimes h')) = F((gg') \otimes (hh')) = (gg',hh') = (g,h)(g',h') = F(g \otimes h) F(g' \otimes h) $$ and that $$ F(r(g \otimes h)) = r(g,h) = rF(g \otimes h), $$ so how do I go about showing that $$ F( (g\otimes h) + (g' \otimes h')) = F( g\otimes h) + F(g' \otimes h'). $$  Clearly, $g \otimes h + g' \otimes h' \neq (g+g') \otimes (h + h')$ in general so I feel like I have to be missing something silly or I'm going about this completely wrong?  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Saying $F(g \otimes h) = (g,h)$ is not specifying $F$ everywhere in an explicit way.  Therefore what was the justification for your remark "Clearly this is invertible"?  And what was your justification for writing $F(r(g \otimes h)) = r(g,h)$? If you were implicitly thinking $F$ is $R$-linear then you should not have been "stuck" on the additivity of $F$. If you were not yet believing $F$ is $R$-linear then you could not have justified the calculation of $F(r(g \otimes h))$. Either way, the main gap in what you are doing is not using the universal mapping property to *define* $F$ everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to appeal to the universal property of the tensor product and the fact that universal objects are defined uniquely up to (unique) isomorphism.

So, we want to show that a given algebra homomorphism $\varphi\colon R[G]\times R[H]\to A$ uniquely induces an algebra homomorphism $\overline\varphi\colon R[G\times H]\to A$ such that $\varphi=\overline\varphi\circ\iota$ where $\iota\colon R[G]\times R[H]\to R[G\times H]$ is the obvious embedding. But this is clear as $\varphi$ is uniquely determined by its values on $g\in G$ and $h\in H$ and hence we can easily define $\overline\varphi$ (uniquely) on the pairs $(g,h)$ which form a basis for $R[G\times H]$.

Comment: That's quite clever, thanks!

Comment: @RedSleuth It's in general a powerful technique to obtain isomorphisms this way if you have a universal property at hand. Glad to help!

Comment: The term "extend" is not the right one for converting a mapping out of $R[G] \times R[H]$ to a mapping out of $R[G \times H]$, since the product set $R[G] \times R[H]$ is not considered to be a subset of $R[G \times H]$.  Similarly, a group homomorphism $G \to H$ that is trivial on a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ does not "extend" to a homomorphism $G/N \to H$.

Comment: @KCd Oh, I see. What would be a better choice of words then; simply "define"?

Comment: You could say "define" or "induces" or "leads to".

Answer (score 0):

One other way to see it is to consider the map $\varphi : R[G \times H] \to R[G] \otimes_R R[H]$ that sends $$\sum_{(g, h) \in G \times H} a_{(g, h)} (g, h) \mapsto \sum_{(g, h) \in G \times H} a_{(g, h)} (g \otimes_R h).$$ Understanding the sum on the right-hand side as a double sum $$\sum_{h \in H} \sum_{g \in G} b_g c_h (g \otimes_R h) = \biggl(\sum_{g \in G} b_g g \biggr) \otimes_R \biggl(\sum_{h \in H} c_h h \biggr)$$ with $b_g c_h = a_{(g, h)},$ it follows that $\varphi$ is surjective, as every element of $R[G] \otimes_R R[H]$ is a finite $R$-linear combination of elementary tensors. Of course, $\varphi$ is injective, so it is an isomorphism.